# Rectangle collision determine side

Tags: c++, 2d, collision-detection

Suppose i have a rectangle defined by a point (its upper left corner), and a width and height like this (in C++):

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(float _x, float _y, float _width, float _height);
    ~Rectangle();

    float X, Y, Width, Height;

    bool intersects(Rectangle& _rect)
    {
        return (
        (X < _rect.X + _rect.Width)&&
        (X + Width > _rect.X)&&
        (Y < _rect.Y + _rect.Height)&&
        (Y + Height > _rect.Y)
        );
    }
}
```

The above `intersects` function returns true if the rectangles overlap - if they collide. But what if i want to find out *which side* of the rectangle the other rectangle collided with? How would i do that (efficiently, but not a priority)?

Comment: Your function returns `true` when rectangle A is completely inside rectangle B. On what side do they "collide"? What about rectangles with two overlapping sides?

Comment: ... or when one corner of a rectangle is completely inside the other one, with the other three corners completely outside. Now what?

Comment: Well, this is just generally to test if they "touch" each other. Which is sufficient for me. If a rectangle is inside another recrangle and this returns true, thats acceptable for me. But i want to know, with this kind of a rectangle, how i can check for proper collision, that is, finding out which side collides with another rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of collision is detected there are 16 different variants[image]

How I got this table? There are 4 different places avaliable for upper-left corner of the red rect. First line is first variant, second line - second variant and so on. Also there are 4 diff. places for down-right corner of the red rect. And I also put each variant in a separate column.
For example, we want to know does the top side of (*this) (let it be red) collide with _rect (let it be blue). It's true for variants 9,10,11,12,14,16. So the case is
`(_rect.Y < Y < _rect.Y + _rect.Height) && 
(X < _rect.X || X + Width > _rect.X + _rect.Width)`

Comment: can you please add numbers to the individual cases? i dont quite get your numbering scheme, thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @calcyss Variants on the first line are 1,2,3,4; on the second - 5,6,7,8 abd so on